# How to write sort function

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a field and i must write function in Meta class that sorted my date in my fields field. Please help me

```
from django.db import models

class Aaa(models.Model):
    fields = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'project'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend having a long, concentrated read of the documentation, in particular: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    test_case_counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    my_date_field = models.DateField(auto_now=True,auto_add=True)

    class Meta: # notice indentation
        ordering = ['my_date_field']
        app_label = 'project'
```